# Many css ids to the same jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#myInputId1").blur(function()
```

How can i do:

```
#myInputId1, #myInputId2, #myInputId3 -> same blur function
```

I believe that's not hard, but tried with many things and cant!

Comment: that is what css classes are for! Add the same class to all your inputs and use it instead of IDs in your jquery!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#myInputId1, #myInputId2, #myInputId3").blur(function(){
   //your code
});
```

Or other way you can check all id that starts with `myInputId` :

```
$('input[id^=myInputId]').blur(function(){
   //your code
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Apply same css class to all elements which you want.Then use the following code

```
$('.className').blur(function(){
     ....
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply -

```
$('#myInputId1, #myInputId2, #myInputId3').blur(...)
```

http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Answer (score 0):

[As Api suggested](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) `[jQuery( "selector1, selector2, selectorN" )]`

```
$("#myInputId1, #myInputId2, #myInputId3").blur(function(){


}
```

http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[id^="myInputId"]').blur(function() {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
$('input[id*="myInputId"]').blur(function()
```

Answer (score 0):

One further option is to use delegation:

```
var relevantIDs = ['myInputID1','myInputID2','entirelyDifferentID'];
$('body').on('blur', function (e){
    var self = e.target;
    if (self.id && $.inArray(self.id, relevantIDs) > -1) {
        $(self).plugin();
    }
});
```

Unfortunately this explicitly requires that the element `id`s are all predefined in an array, though it allows for those `id`s to not have a specific pattern (a requirement, obviously, of the attribute-starts-with, or ends-with selectors).

For performance reasons it's better to select the closest shared ancestor element of all the targeted elements rather than the document `body`.

As noted elsewhere, though, while there are workarounds to allow this multiple `id` based selection, it's much easier, simpler, and more clear to use a common attribute such as a `class`.

References:

- [`$.inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 0):

Or you can bind event on the parent:

```
$(container).on('blur', 'input', function(){
    //do something
})
```